# Hay alguna manera de reproducir música desde spotify en un bot de discord?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Estuve investigando sobre cómo poder reproducir música de Spotify en mi bot de discord mediante javascript, encontré una posibilidad con lavalink, pero nada, así que pido ayuda aquí por si hay alguna manera de hacerlo, ya que Nekotina lo hace, y con eso sé que es posible. Por favor y gracias.

Comment: *¿Hay alguna manera de...?* y la respuesta siempre será sí, no, posiblemente sí, posiblemente no.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Estoy intentando reproducir música de spotify mediante mi bot de discord, pero tengo unos problemas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/estoy-intentando-reproducir-m%c3%basica-de-spotify-mediante-mi-bot-de-discord-pero-t)

Comment: no lo hace, hice esta pregunta porque ya no estoy utilizando algún plugin, además que todo bot de spotify que encuentro está desactualizado, o reproduce canciones de Youtube.